# Composition of subharmonic function and covering map is subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are Riemann surfaces.
>
> Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a covering map, and $u:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a subharmonic function on $Y$. Show that $u\circ \pi$ is subharmonic on $X$.
>
> Here, we say $\varphi$ is subharmonic on $U$ if any closed disc $D(z,r) \subset U$ of center $z$ and radius $r$ one has
> $$\varphi(z) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(z+ re^{i\theta}) \, d\theta.$$

---

A covering map is a "local homeomorphism". But without the analytic structure, I have no idea.

And by definition, for every $y\in Y$, we have some neighborhood $U$ of $y$ and the homeomorphism from some component of $f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ to $U$. But here, to show $f\circ u$ is subharmonic, we need to pick the neighborhood of $x\in X$ at first. So the condition is useless for me...

Comment: You're leaving out various important facts - as stated the question is meaningless. In particular, if you don't tell us anything about $X$ and $Y$ the notion of "subharmonic function on X (or Y)" makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich fixed! thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that before the notion of a subharmonic function on a Riemann surface really makes sense we need to know that the composition of a subharmonic function and a biholomorphic map is subharmonic. (You might note that the definition of "subharmonic" that you gave really makes sense only in the plane, not an a Riemann surface.)

In any case that's true, and not hard to prove. Hence the answer to your question is yes if $\pi$ is a *holoomorphic* covering map, since in that case it is locally biholomorphic. It's not clear whether "covering map" is meant to imply holmorphic in this context.

But if $\pi$ is just a topological covering map then what you say you want to prove seems ridiculous -  why would it be true? For an actual counterexample let $X=Y=\Bbb C$, $\pi(x,y)=(x,2y)$ and $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$.
(And of course recall that a smooth function in the plane is subharmonic if and only if its Laplacian is non-negative.)

Comment: For your first question, I think we can generalize the definition by using the atlas and "pull-back" to define the subharmonic function on Riemann surfaces.

Comment: I have the same feeling that this question is impossible to do but I was not sure before. And your counterexample is good! Thanks!

Comment: @LeoGardon Using an atlas is exactly what I had in mind - if that's not going to depend on the particular choice of atlas we need to know what II said about composition with biholomorphic maps. If this problem is like an exercise in a book or something I bet they're just assuming it's a holomorphic covering map, given the context.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you again!